# rails 4 adding 'show' view for already existing model

Tags: json, view, ruby-on-rails-4, show

I have an already existing Artist model and controller but didn't scaffold it and get views because I don't want to be them created through a form.

I want to add a show.html.erb file for the Artist view though so that a user can view a page for a specific artist. Is there an easy way to manually do this by creating a json file similar to what is created when one scaffold's something? I tried to create one and then make a view similar to what it would look like had I scaffolded, but kept getting a lot of undefined method errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify, you have a Artist model and controller and want a show.html.erb file? Something like this should work. In your routes file, add a line that refines which actions you want artists to have:

```
resources :artists, only: [:show] #and any other actions you want inside the brackets
```

In your artists controller:

```
# GET /artists/1
# GET /artists/1.json
def show 
   #whatever info needs to be shared with the view
   @artist = Artist.find(params[:id])
end
```

Then create a file inside *app/views/artists* and call it **show.html.erb**

Comment: Ah thanks, I already ended up just remaking artist with a scaffold. If I don't want a user to be able to navigate to artist/new though to create a new artist, can I just delete that file? or what is the right way to go about preventing that?

Comment: I would specify in the config.routes file that the new action isn't suppose to exist ( resources :artists, except: :new  ) and then you can just delete the new action from the controller and delete the new.html.erb file as well.

Comment: Section 4.6 Restricting the Routes Created in the Rails Routing Guide explains this a bit more.